# How do I go about upgrading jQuery in my project?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to work out the best way to upgrade jQuery.

Let's say I am using jQuery v1.4.4, and I want to upgrade to 1.7.1.

If I want to update, should I remove `jquery-1.4.4.js` completely from my project or should I keep `jquery-1.4.4.js` in addition to `jquery-1.7.1.js`?

Also there may be some jQuery files that may be referencing `jquery-1.4.4.js`, What is the best way of upgrading these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new version of jQuery should completely *replace* the old version, so you could remove the `<script>` that included the old version and replace it with a new `<script>` block.

You will find that a jQuery update does not normally include many *breaking changes* (changes that will break code used with a previous version), and so, for the majority of cases, you should not get any problems when you upgrade.

However, to be sure, you should look at the [release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) for the version you're upgrading to (and indeed, all the versions you're bypassing), to check you won't be affected by any of the changes.

Code does not *reference* a specific version of jQuery. Code that uses jQuery simply uses the jQuery methods and constructors (`jQuery` and `$`), and expects a certain method signature (form of accepted parameters and return type). Upgrading to a new version *might* remove these methods or change the signature of them, and it's **this** you need to watch out for.

Comment: so if I am also using jquery.validate.js. This does not have any version number in it.  Does this mean its version independent or should I replace it with jquery.validate-1.7.js ?

Comment: @imak: this is where my last paragraph comes into play. It is version independant **on the premise** that the methods it uses have not changed in the versions of jQuery that have been released since it was created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes replace the script tag for the old version with the new one.

The only way another file, on the client side (unless you're using LAB or something similar) is by including a script tag in your HTML page. Without any loaders JavaScript files cannot call out to other JavaScript files.

That being said make sure you test thoroughly before deploying!